# true or false if variable defined gotchas

Tags: javascript

If a value must be defined to true or false, based off the check off another value, are there any gotchas in doing :

```
!!someValue
```

Just a quick run against chrome's engine gives:

```
boolCheck=function(someValue){
    return !! someValue;
}

console.log(boolCheck());           //false
console.log(boolCheck(undefined));  //false
console.log(boolCheck(null));       //false
console.log(boolCheck(1));          //true
console.log(boolCheck({va:1}));     //true
console.log(boolCheck("someTS"));   //true
console.log(boolCheck(boolCheck));  //true
```

which SEEMS to work....

Comment: What are you asking here? What is true and what is false in a boolean context is well-defined. Not sure what "gotchas" you are seeking.

Comment: What on earth do you mean gotchas in doing?  Why are we looking for gotchas in something that makes no sense to do in the first place?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: You should use !!!!!!!!!!someValue to make it cooler!

Comment: @skovalyov Psh, I use double the amount of `!` than that!

Comment: If depends on what is "normal" to you or not. In Python, an empty list or dictionary (Javascript array or object, respectively) or string is technically "False". That doesn't seem to be the same for Javascript - try passing `[]` to `boolCheck`.

Comment: most sane people prefer `Boolean(x)` to `!!x`, as it is more straight-forward and `!!x` just calls the `Boolean` constructor internally anyways.

Comment: @jbabey: It does an internal *ToBoolean* conversion, but I doubt that any implementation would actually call the constructor function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `!` operator always returns either `true` or `false`, so assuming evaluation of `x` completes normally, `!!x` is a boolean value that is the equivalent of `Boolean(x)` where `Boolean` is the EcmaScript builtin function.

http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.9 says

> ## 11.4.9 Logical NOT Operator ( `!` )
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* : `!` *UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Let oldValue be ToBoolean(GetValue(expr)).
> 3. If oldValue is `true`, return `false`.
> 4. Return `true`.

http://es5.github.com/#x9.2 explains how *ToBoolean* works

> ## 9.2 ToBoolean
>
> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:
>
> Table 11 — ToBoolean Conversions
>
> ```
> Argument Type    Result 
> Undefined        false
> Null             false
> Boolean          The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
> Number           The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
> String           The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
> Object           true
> ```

---

The above table explains most of your examples, but it may not be obvious why

> ```
>  console.log(boolCheck());
> ```

is `false`.  When you call a function with fewer actual arguments than formal parameters, the extra parameters have the value `undefined` and, as the table above shows `!!undefined` is `false`.

---

> are there any gotchas in doing : `!!someValue`?

The intent is less clear than `Boolean(someValue)`, but it will work consistently across platforms and most experienced Javascript devs will recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not strongly typed, so if you **not** some value it will produce different results depending on the type passed in. So yes, there are plenty of gotchas!

Answer (score 0):

That's basically means that if it's 0, null, undefined, or false then evaluate to false, anything else evaluate to true.

Which, by the way, if being used in a situation that is automatically being cast to a boolean is the exact same as just evaluating the variable itself. "if(someValue){}" will be the same as "if(!!someValue){}" because the if statement will automatically evaluate the contents to a boolean, and the !! is just doing the same thing (redundantly in that situation). But the plain fact is that 99.9999% of the time when you're using any sort of boolean it will eventually be evaluated in that sort of way, which is why !! really has very little place in code except to be redundant.

But in the end it's your definition of "gotchas" that is too vague to be understood here. I have no freakin idea if "null" evaluating to "false" will break your intended usage or not!